Merge two maps and keep null values
I hope all is good for you.
I have two maps and I want to keep null values. I know that merge function can't manage null values but I need to keep null data and use the Binary Operation.
How I can manage my code to avoid NPE.
  private Map<String, Object> mergeMaps(
      Map<String, Object> map1, Map<String, Object> map2) {
    return Stream.of(map1, map2)
        .map(Map::entrySet)
        .flatMap(Collection::stream)
        .collect(
            Collectors.toMap(
                Map.Entry::getKey,
                Map.Entry::getValue,
                (v1, v2) -> v1 != null
                            && StringUtils.isNotEmpty(v1.toString()) 
                         ? v1 
                         : v2
                ));
  }

Sample test code:
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, Object> map1 = new HashMap<>();
    map1.put("k1", null);
    map1.put("k2", "2");
    map1.put("k3", null);
    Map<String, Object> map2 = new HashMap<>();
    map2.put("k1", "1");
    map2.put("k2", null);
    map2.put("k3", null);

    var result = mergeMaps(map1, map2);

    System.out.println(result);
  }

should output something like {k1=1, k2=2, k3=null}; k1 having been replaced by map2, k2 staying from map1, and k3 being null in both.
Thanks a lot.

Use Map<String, Optional<Object>>

Why can't you just deal with nulls? (v1, v2) -> (v1 == null || v1.toString().isEmpty()) ? v2 : v1

Because Map.Entry::getValue return NPE

@daniu it's not possible without using Optional ?

Where does it say in the documentation that Map.Entry::getValue throws NPE? That function itself certainly doesn't throw: it just returns null if the value is null. The toMap function throws NPE only if you pass null instead of Map.Entry::getValue. It doesn't matter if getValue() returns null.

@k314159 The issue is that Map#merge cannot handle entries with a value of null, which is used in the toMap collector.

@daniu That would be a bad use of Optional. I recommend against it.

Your code doesn’t compile. Please remove the spurious semicolon. Other than that, if your code throws a NPE, isn’t that from v1.toString() since v1 can be null according to what you say? Please explain what you need StringUtils.isNotEmpty() for at all? Without this information I can’t seem to understand your requirements?

@Bourg I feel the downvotes and nitpicky comments do border on trolling, but they do have a point; it did take a moment to understand what you're asking and what the issue is. For future questions, you should probably add code with sample input showing the problem (like I did in my answer).

@daniu I disagree that wanting to understand the requirements is on the border of nit-picking. I have downvoted and voted to close.

@daniu I was hoping I was helping the OP to improve the question so that also future readers may understand it. I don’t see much value in keeping an unclear question around.

@Anonymous Yeah like I said your points are valid. However, I think a better approach is to just provide a proper example - you have edit rights, you can just remove the superfluous semicolon yourself, takes less time than telling OP to do it. Also, I already removed the NPE you mentioned, so this point isn't valid anymore, and neither the accompanying close vote. Leaves the missing test input data which is the best point, but available in my answer; I can move it to the question, but I don't see how this invalidates the post overall.

Bourg, the best thing you could do for users of Stack Overflow would still be to edit your question and make completely clear how you want to prioritize (a) nulls (b) empty strings (c) objects returning an empty string from their toString method and (d) other objects (normal objects) coming from values of the two maps. Bonuses for you include the existing answer might be improved, I will retract my downvote and would vote to reopen, which ultimately might make it possible that you get more answers.

@daniu Thanks for improving the question. It’s clearly improved, yet still unclear, and I haven’t got the information needed to clarify, so I can’t do anything further from here, sorry.

I'd go for
  Map<String, Object> mergeMaps(Map<String, Object> map1,
                                Map<String, Object> map2) {
    Map<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>(map1);
    map2.forEach((k, v) -> {
      var value = result.get(k);
      if (value == null || value.toString().isEmpty()) {
        result.put(k, v);
      }
    });
    return result;
  }

Which runs fine for the test case.

If map1 has an entry "k1": "" (value is null string) then the OP wants the merged map to contain the value from map2. Your solution doesn't do that.

@k314159 yeah, trivial, adjusted.

This is now a good answer. I'd change result.put(map2.get(k)); to result.put(v); though.

Thanks @daniu and k314159 for your help. It's good for me.

two upvotes and accepted, but does not even compile :- / --- 1) missing );; 2) put() needs two arguments; 3) missing isNullOrEmpty(Object)

@k314159 If map1 has an entry "k1": "" (…) then the OP wants the merged map to contain the value from map2. No, nowhere did the OP say that.

@Anonymous yes they did: StringUtils.isNotEmpty(v1.toString()) ? v1 : v2

@k314159 They did not. They talked about nulls. The call you are quoting will fail with a NullPointerException is v1 is null, so it has never worked, and what the OP intended with it, is up to interpretation.
